# Geometric interpretation of this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, analytic-geometry, intuition

For real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n,c_1,\ldots,c_n$ it holds that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_kc_k\le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2 \right)^{1/2} .
$$

Is there a geometric interpretation for this inequality?

The RHS is simply the product of the Euclidean lengths of the vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$, where $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n),$ etc. But I'm not sure about the LHS. Does the LHS have a geometric meaning?

I'm thinking that there may be a nice geometric interpretation because this inequality looks a lot like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but with three vectors instead of two.

---

Here's a proof of this inequality:

If one of the factors on the RHS is zero, the inequality holds trivially. Otherwise divide by the RHS and write $\hat a = {a \over|| a||}$, $\hat b = {b \over|| a||}$, $\hat c = {c \over|| c||}$. Then 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \hat a_k \hat b_k \hat c_k \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \hat a_k^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \hat b_k^2 \hat c_k^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \hat a_k^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \hat b_k^2 \right)^{1/2} = 1,
$$

where the first inequality is due to Cauchy-Schwarz and the second inequality follows because all components of the normed vector $\hat c$ must have absolute value $\le 1$. Multiplying by $||a||\, ||b||\, ||c||$ then yields the claim.

Comment: I wonder if a possible geometric interpretation could go as follows: of all rhomboids having sides congruent to vectoes  $a, b, c$, the maximum volume is achieved when the sides are mutually perpendicular. I will attempt to work the details out in due course.

Comment: qv https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092515/33079

Comment: @AakashM this does not answer the question because the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $n$ dimensions still holds for only two vectors. My question is about three vectors in $n$ dimensions.